# Need to upload an Excel file into Shiny and save in S3

Tags: r, excel, amazon-s3, shiny

I needed to upload an excel file into my Shiny App and subsequently save the file into S3.

The issue is that i have multiple sheets in the Excel file that i need to preserve.

When I upload the file into Shiny, it only allows me to upload a single sheet a time. When i save this sheet into S3, i loose all formatting and formulae. Only a single sheet would get saved which contains only values, much like a .csv or a R data frame.

I was wondering if there is any workaround for this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),

      # Input: Select quotes ----
      radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                   choices = c(None = "",
                               "Double Quote" = '"',
                               "Single Quote" = "'"),
                   selected = '"'),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(

      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")

    )

  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.

    req(input$file1)

    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
             header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep,
             quote = input$quote)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })

}
# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or...this...

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('file1', 'Insert File', accept = c(".xlsx")),
  textInput('file1sheet','Name of Sheet (Case-Sensitive)'),
  tableOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  sheets_name <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$file1)) {
      return(excel_sheets(path = input$file1$datapath))  
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  output$value <- renderTable({
    if (!is.null(input$file1) && 
        (input$file1sheet %in% sheets_name())) {
      return(read_excel(input$file1$datapath, 
                        sheet = input$file1sheet))
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution definitely works, but not exactly what i was looking for. Is there a way to store an Excel file in shinyio and then download it from the server using a shiny front end?